# Java: Error parse date's string to date object

Tags: java

I try to convert string to date on java. I read and try the example from this website ["Java Date and Calendar examples"](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/) but I still cannot compile and run it.

This is my code.

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class JavaApplication5 {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String dateInString = "31-08-1982 10:20:56";
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
    }

}
```

And I got this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.text.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

What I missing or do it wrong? Thank you for help.

Comment: Yes error is so clear, either you need to put your `sdf.parse()` inside a try catch or use throws clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`java.text.ParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) is [checked exception](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions)

> A checked exception is a type of exception that must be either caught or declared in the method in which it is thrown

So... You might declare it in [`throws`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) list

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or should properly handle it it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // do proper thing here like try another
        // format or log/rethrow/wrap exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for including both ways it can be done. It's also good that you quickly explained checked exceptions since it reveals the cause of the compilation error.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson thanks to you :)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson Well flagging as duplicate would be best, but who would say "no" to some easily farmed reputation, right? :P

Answer (score 0):

Just add your code in try catch block.

```
try {
 //parse code
}
catch (ParseException e) {
 //handling exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all your code in a try/ catch block

```
try{
     // your code here.
 }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: This will work, but it will catch all Exceptions which is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes if you want to catch parsing exception you can replace "Exception" by "ParseException" in catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `try-catch` block like this:

```
try
{
    //...Code.... Mainly below:
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
} catch (ParseException e) 
  //Or any superclass, such as RuntimeException, 
  //although use superclass ONLY to be generic, not otherwise, such as 
  //if you want to handle all exceptions the same way.
{
    //...Handler Code...
}
```

Comment: Edited answer @Tom

Comment: @Tom edited again

Answer (score 0):

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            String dateInString = "31-08-1982 10:20:56";
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Explain your answer